# Call method without self parameter in Perl

Tags: perl, oop, method-call

I would like to know if it is possible to call a method from an object without passing the self argument.

As an example, I have a package:

```
package MyPackage;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {}, $class;
}

sub test {
    print("called(" . join(', ', @_) . ")\n");
}
```

From a script, I call the constructor and then the `test` method:

```
my $obj = MyPackage->new();
$obj->test("str");
```

giving me the following output:

```
called(MyPackage=HASH(0x55b05d481f48), str)
```

Is there any way (even if it's not a best practice or use some "arcane"
features of the language) to call the `test` method using only the reference
`$obj` without having the "self"-parameter passed implicitly.

In a word, is it possible to do something like this:

```
$objXXXXtest("str");
```

with `XXXX` the hypothetical construct and get `called(str)` as output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a little unorthodox, but [`UNIVERSAL::can`](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL#$obj-%3Ecan(-METHOD-)) returns a code reference that you could call without the referent.

```
$obj->can("test")->("str");
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just call the function directly, and not as a method of an object:

```
myPackage::test("str");
```

Comment: Yes, it would be the "normal way" to do it, but I'm only provided the `$obj` reference and I don't know the class of the object.